# Python check if website exists for a list of websites

Tags: python, web

I want to check if a website exists, given a list of websites in the format XXXXX.com, where XXXXX=a 5 digit number. So I want to go through from 00000 up to 99999 and see if those variants of the website exist.

I want to do something like

```
import requests
request = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
if request.status_code == 200:
    print('Web site exists')
else:
    print('Web site does not exist')
```

But generate a list of some sort (or even just export a list to csv), so for each URL, i know if it exists or not.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: So what is wrong with the code you have? Did you get an error? Does it not produce your expected output?

Comment: i want it to iterate over a list, so i have to rerun it for every number from 00000 to 99999

Comment: Great, did you Google how to iterate over a list? How to produce a list of 00000 to 99999? How to execute a function on each item in a list? As it sits, your post doesn't really show that you put any effort into solving your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try combining `xrange` and the string `zfill` method in a loop.

```
import requests


def test_for_200(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    return req.status_code == 200


def numbers():
    for n in xrange(100000):
        yield str(n).zfill(5)


results = {}
for num in numbers():
    url = "http://{}.com".format(num)
    results[num] = test_for_200(url)
```

`results` will look something like this:

```
>>> results
{'00000': True, '00001': False, ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make an assumption that you have a large list of URLs and you want to read them in from some source file, let's say a text file, rather than hard-coding a large list of URLs in Python file, right.  If that's the case, run the script below and you'll get what you want.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

start = time.time()

file = open('C:\\your_path\\check_me.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
urls = file.readlines()

print(urls)

def checkurl(url):
    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        # Return code error (e.g. 404, 501, ...)
        # ...
        print('HTTPError: {}'.format(e.code) + ', ' + url)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        # Not an HTTP-specific error (e.g. connection refused)
        # ...
        print('URLError: {}'.format(e.reason) + ', ' + url)
    else:
        # 200
        # ...
        print('good' + ', ' + url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(processes=20)
    result = p.map(checkurl, urls)

print("done in : ", time.time()-start)
```